# TypeScript extend native objects in a safe way like extension functions via TS transformer

Tags: typescript, extension-methods

TypeScript provides ability to transform AST during compilation.

I wonder if it could be used to extend native objects Object, Array, String in a safe way without tainting its prototypes.

Let's add `isEmpty()` method to `Object`, `Array`, `String` etc. First, we **trick TypeScript with a false declaration** that such method exist:

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    isEmpty(): boolean
  }
  interface Array {
    isEmpty(): boolean
  }
  interface String {
    isEmpty(): boolean
  }
}
```

Then we write **AST transformer** that would turn this TS code we type in editor

```
{ a: 1 }.isEmpty()
[1, 2].isEmpty()
"hello".isEmpty()
```

Into the following **compiled JS code** (we expose `NativeExtensions` globally, we taint the global scope, but just with that one variable)

```
NativeExtensions.isEmpty({ a: 1 })
NativeExtensions.isEmpty([1, 2])
NativeExtensions.isEmpty("hello")
```

And the implementation could be

```
NativeExtensions.isEmpty = (o) => {
  if ('isEmpty' in o) return o.isEmpty()
  if (o instanceof Array) return o.length == 0
  if (typeof o == 'string' || o instanceof String) return o.length == 0
  for (const k in o) if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) return false
  return true
}
```

Do you know if that would be possible and how to write TS Transformer code that would do that? Maybe there's already some effort in that direction?

Comment: Maybe you could read through this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9